# Using Objective-C's method_invoke to call a void method under ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

On iOS, I'm attempting to use the `method_invoke` function from the Objective-C runtime ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_51)) in order to call an Objective-C method that is declared with a return type of `void`.

This works fine in non-ARC code, but with ARC enabled, I get a crash after the invocation of the method in `objc_retain`. I think what's going on is that the compiler notices `method_invoke`'s return type of `id`, and attempts to retain the value returned by `method_invoke` (note that `method_invoke` is meant to return the return value of the method it invokes).

What's the correct way to let the compiler know that in this specific case, the return value of `method_invoke` is garbage and should not be retained? The following appears to work, but seems conceptually wrong:

`(void)((__bridge void *)method_invoke(target, method));`

This does not seem to work (still crashes in `objc_retain`:

`(void)method_invoke(target, method)`

Is there a more correct approach here?

Comment: get `IMP` and cast it to correct type and call it directly

Comment: I don't think `method_invoke` attempts to retain the return value, but ARC calls `objc_retain` on all parameters passed in to a method.  Are you sure `target` is allocated?  Does execution stop on a breakpoint inside your method?  You can also set a breakpoint on `objc_retain` to see when it's called.

Comment: Calling IMP directly has the same problem. target is definitely a valid object, and yes, I can confirm that the method does get invoked.

Answer (score 4):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507456/sudzc-arc-version-objc-msgsend-call-causes-exc-bad-access-using-64-bit-archite) actually gave me the idea for a better solution.

The basic approach was to create a function pointer referencing `method_invoke` with the correct signature (void return type) and cast `method_invoke` into this function pointer, and then call through the function pointer.

So, roughly:

```
static void (*_method_invoke_void)(id, Method, ...) = (void (*)(id, Method, ...)) method_invoke;
... snip ...
_method_invoke_void(target, method);
```

Comment: Casting method_invoke to the correct function pointer type is required with or without ARC. It just happens that ARC is more likely to break if you fail to do so.

Comment: Note that you must also replace `...` with the correct parameter list for your call.