# Too many arguments to function call, expected 0 method_invoke

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to run the method `id method_invoke ( id receiver, Method m, ... );` from the Objective-C runtime library but the compiler is saying I'm passing too many arguments, with it expecting 0. Why might this be? (`swizzledMethodOriginalImplementation` is of type `Method`)

```
-(NSMenu*) blah2: (NSEvent*)anEvent :(NSRect) cellFrame :(NSView*) aView { 
     NSMenu *contextMenu = method_invoke(self, swizzledMethodOriginalImplementation, anEvent, cellFrame, aView);
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the actual code giving you the problem.

Comment: Duly noted. Code is there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `method_invoke` wrong. One must never actually *call* `method_invoke` directly. It doesn't know what arguments to expect. That is why its declaration, in the documentation, is written in a completely open-ended form:

```
id method_invoke ( id receiver, Method m, ... );
```

One must first *cast* the `method_invoke` function to the *correct* function pointer type for the method in question. I don't see you doing that.

Comment: See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694173/using-objective-cs-invoke-method-to-call-a-void-method-under-arc.