# EXC_BAD_ACCESS, code 1, iOS 7.0.x 64bit devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

App that I am currently developing is running perfectly on simulator, but since  Xcode upgrade to 5.1 I have problem running app on devices. If I run  app on any non 64 bit device on any iOS it runs fine, but if I run it on  64bit device (iPhone 5s, iPad Air), on iOS 7.0.x app crashes with error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x50111f87261d1146)

line 16 main.m

@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([MobileUIApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

If I run the app on 64bit device with iOS 7.1, it runs fine. I believe that issue is with my Target->Architectures where it is setup "Base SDK - Latest iOS (iOS 7.1)", but I cannot change that to any earler version. And my iOS Deployment Target is setup to iOS 6.0. Does anybody know any solution for this? I don't want to publish it and come into situation where person has iOS 7.0.3 and app crashes on his phone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had similar problem. When you updated Xcode there was probably warning to "Validate Project setting". When you did that, there was checkbox to automatically select "Architectures". And this is where my problem lay.

To fix it change "Architectures" and "Valid Architectures" in build settings for **Project AND Target** to "**armv7 armv7s**" (right now you probably have selected Standard architectures) and set "**Build Active Architectures only**" to NO.

Comment: Just to add in, this is not a possible solution anymore as Apple requires uploaded builds to support arm64 as well

Comment: Then what would be the solution ? I've got this issue and indeed removing arm64 support "fix" it... but is not acceptable. What should we do ? :/

Comment: I've found my solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507456/sudzc-arc-version-objc-msgsend-call-causes-exc-bad-access-using-64-bit-archite