# iOS app crashing on iPhone 6 [iOS version : 8.4] device with exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

iOS app crashing on iPhone 6 [iOS version : 8.4] device with exception

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000008a8302b7f , but its working in iPhone 6 simulator and other apple devices with same os version:
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             digitalAGENCY [1056]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8F3C89F0-98DB-45F9-94BB-FE80E9DECE3F/digitalAGENCY.app/digitalAGENCY
Identifier:          com.evero.services
Version:             3.3 (3.3)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Date/Time:           2015-07-22 10:45:49.352 -0400
Launch Time:         2015-07-22 10:45:07.207 -0400
OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
Report Version:      105
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000008a8302b7f Triggered by Thread:  0
```

[image]

Comment: Can you replicate this? If not you need to symbolicate the crash log. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode-6">how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode-6

Comment: use the SudzC classes and when I change my app from ARM-32 to 64 it become crashed.I solved this problem by changing the code as referred in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507456/sudzc-arc-version-objc-msgsend-call-causes-exc-bad-access-using-64-bit-archite But this links only help to run in ARM-64 for supporting ARM-32 I rewrite the code as ((void(*)(id, SEL, id))objc_msgSend)(self.handler, self.action, output);